# How to automate Visual Studio Code extensions packaging in Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, vscode-extensions

I have successfully setup Azure DevOps to automatically build my Visual Studio Code extension from a git repo, but I cannot find a way to generate the .vsix file. That is, I can create it locally, but I want to generate it for every build automatically, so I can download it once the build has finished.

Thanks!

Comment: Which commnad do you use locally do generate the .vsix file? can you share your build definition?

Comment: I was looking for a pre-canned way of doing it. I was thinking that such things should come out of the box in Azure, but it looks it doesn't. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this extension to generate Visual Studio extension's VSIX: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-developer-tools-build-tasks&targetId=18354d24-b805-4494-a4b9-c57440acfeea

This extension is free, and it's from Microsoft DevLabs. 
It is also open source at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks

**NOTE**: According to my own experience using this extension, it is not compatible with some releases of Visual Studio *before* Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. It is compatible with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1/Update 2/Update 3, and Visual Studio 2017 release 15.3.0 or later.

Comment: Does this work for Visual Studio Code or just for Visual Studio?

Comment: @qadram this extension works for both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio.

Comment: According to [this question](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks/issues/137), this extension doesn't work for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have found my own answer, by installing vsce, and calling it for packaging the .vsix

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Install vsce'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'install -g vsce'     

  - script: 'vsce package'
    displayName: 'Package .vsix'
```

Comment: This solution won't work consistently. Because the `vsce` will break if Azure DevOps default hosted agents update the NodeJS and the npm.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: you can't control how the npm task works. because it depends on what is the nodejs version installed in the build agents of azure devops build, and it is up to Microsoft to use which version.